# Postgresql trigger to calculate total score

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am trying to learn how to create a trigger in postgresql.  I have a table

Thread_user - table name

```
thread_id user_id points
```

Thread - table name

```
thread_id total_points
```

I want to on update of any `thread_user` row to update the total points in the thread table.  I need to basically `select * from thread_user where thread_id = <thread_id of inserted item>` and then add the points then update `thread_points` in the threads table.  I believe this is done in triggers but maybe a stored procedure would be better.

Comment: Values that can be calcualted from data in your tables should not normally be stored in the database. You risk saving wrong data.

Comment: Zahrec, I understand that, but the actual worth of those numbers compared to the potential run time of figuring that out every time is worth the difference.

Comment: Okay, that a proper reason. Just wanted to be sure that you knew that. I've given a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step is to make a function which calculates the sum of points and updates a row in the `calculated_points` table.

Thereafter you'll have to create a trigger which is called upon inserting a row in the `user_points` table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_points CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE user_points (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id     INT NOT NULL,
    points      INT NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS calculated_points CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE calculated_points (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id     INT  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    points      INT NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO calculated_points (user_id, points)
    VALUES
        (1, 0),
        (2, 0);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_total_points() 
RETURNS trigger AS $calculate_total_points$
BEGIN
    UPDATE calculated_points 
        SET points = (SELECT SUM(points)
                         FROM user_points
                         WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id)
         WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$calculate_total_points$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER points_added
  AFTER INSERT
  ON user_points
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate_total_points();
```

Comment: NB: this will get slower and slower over time, since *all* rows from `user_points` must be read (inside `calculate_total_points`) each time a single row is inserted. So if `user_points` contains e.g. 100 million rows, then inserting a single row into the table will cause a read of 100 million rows.